# Callback function when bootstrap modal is closed by clicking outside it

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am calling the `submit` function with three parameters when either of the close buttons are clicked.

```
<div class="modal" ng-controller="emailViewController">
        <div class="modal-header" >
            <button type="button" class="close" ng-click = "submit(information.add, information.subject, information.emailContent); close(); clear()">×</button>
            <h3>Compose Email</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form >
                <tags options="{addable: true}" typeahead-options="typeaheadOpts" data-model="information.add" data-src="toPerson as toPerson for toPerson in to"></tags>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" style="width:95%;" data-ng-model = "information.subject"><br />
                <textarea style="width:95%;" rows="10" data-ng-model = "information.emailContent"></textarea>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn" ng-click = "submit(information.add, information.subject, information.emailContent); close(); clear()">Close</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click = "close(); clear()">Send</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have the following questions:

1) How do I call the `submit` function with the same three parameters (`information.add, information.subject, information.emailContent`) when the user clicks anywhere outside the `modal` to close it.

Just to avoid confusion, I am already calling the `submit` function when the `close` buttons are clicked. I am just not sure how to call it when the user clicks outside the `modal` (not on the close buttons) to close it.

I tried using the `hidden.bs.modal` event because it fires when the `modal` closes, but couldn't get it to work.

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $scope.submit(add, subject, emailContent);
        });
```

2) How to call the `submit` function when the user closes the browser?

**ATTEMPT 1**

I realized I was not calling the right parameters in the `submit` function when the `hidden.bs.modal` event was firing so, I modified the code as follows:

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $scope.submit($scope.information.add, $scope.information.subject, $scope.information.emailContent)
    });
```

The `submit` function stores the three values in `localStorage`.

The above code stores the value of `information.add` in `localStorage`, but it does not store the values of `information.subject` and `information.emailContent` in `localStorage`

**ATTEMPT 2**

`submit` function is attached to the `$scope` of this controller (`emailViewController`)

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var emailViewController = function (fetchDataService,
                                        $scope,$filter,$timeout, $localStorage) {

          $scope.information = {
              add: [],
              subject: [],
              emailContent: []
            };

         $scope.submit = function (add, subject, emailContent) {
          console.log(add);
          console.log(subject);
          console.log(emailContent);

          if (! ($localStorage.add instanceof Array) ) {
                $localStorage.add = [];
            }

          if(add.length != 0) {
            $localStorage.add.push(add);
          }

            if (! ($localStorage.subject instanceof Array) ) {
                $localStorage.subject = [];
            }

          if(subject != "") {
            $localStorage.subject.push(subject);
            console.log("after localStorage" + subject);
          }

            if (! ($localStorage.emailContent instanceof Array) ) {
                $localStorage.emailContent = [];
            }

          if(emailContent != "") {
            $localStorage.emailContent.push(emailContent);
            }
         };

        $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $scope.submit($scope.information.add, $scope.information.subject, $scope.information.emailContent)
        });

         $scope.localStorage = $localStorage;
         console.log($scope.localStorage);
    };

    angular.module('iisEmail')
        .controller ('emailViewController',
        ['fetchDataService', '$scope','$filter', '$timeout', '$localStorage', emailViewController]);
}());
```

After adding `Attempt 1` to the controller, a new issue is occurring. To avoid this, I had to remove `Attempt 1` from the controller.

This was the problem that was occurring - When the `close` buttons are clicked, `submit` is called. After `Attempt 1`, `submit` was called even when `hidden.bs.modal` event was triggered. As a result, the values of the three parameters were getting stored in localStorage twice.

**ATTEMPT 3**

I tried to use `onBlur` instead of `hidden.bs.modal`, but the event is not triggering.

```
$('.modal').on('blur', function () {
            console.log("Blurred");
            $scope.submit($scope.information.add, $scope.information.subject, $scope.information.emailContent)
        });
```

**ATTEMPT 4**

When I do `console.log($scope)`, I see the value of the three parameters entered by the user in the `localStorage` object. This is exactly what I want, but the values are not getting stored in `Local Storage`. So, when I open dev tools and check the `Local Storage`, I don't see the values entered by the user.

Essentially, I am able to see the data in the `localStorage` object because I am doing this `$scope.localStorage = $localStorage` in my controller (`emailViewController` in `Attempt 2`), but I don't see the data entered by the user in the browser's `Local Storage`

**ATTEMPT 5**

I am not calling the `submit` function from the view anymore because I am using the `hidden.bs.modal` event. Now, when I click on the close buttons, `hidden.bs.modal` is triggered and `Submit` is called. I can see the values entered by the user in the `localStorage` object and in the devtools `Local Storage`. This is working perfectly.

When the user clicks outside the modal to close it (not on the buttons), `hidden.bs.modal` is triggered and `submit` is called. In this case, I can see the values entered by the user in the `localStorage` object, but I cannot see the values in the devtools `Local Storage`.

```
<div class="modal" ng-controller="emailViewController">
        <div class="modal-header" >
            <button type="button" class="close" ng-click = "close(); clear()">×</button>
            <h3>Compose Email</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form >
                <tags options="{addable: true}" typeahead-options="typeaheadOpts" data-model="information.add" data-src="toPerson as toPerson for toPerson in to"></tags>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" style="width:95%;" data-ng-model = "information.subject"><br />
                <textarea style="width:95%;" rows="10" data-ng-model = "information.emailContent"></textarea>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn" ng-click = "close(); clear()">Close</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click = "close(); clear()">Send</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: hey can you make demo of this in jsfiddle..?

Comment: did you try `on blur`

Comment: Have you tried to just log on event hidden.bs.modal?

Comment: Please take a look at the `Attempt 3` section of my question. @johnny5

Comment: try on `focusout` instead then

Comment: @johnny5 I think we have managed to identify the problem. I don't think it is related to the event. Please take a look at the `Attempt 4` section of my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure your are initializing bootstrap js correctly?

I've made a simple codepen: http://codepen.io/dschu/pen/LpYdZY?editors=101

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  console.log('IT IS HIDDEN!')
});
```

Check out your console. "IT IS HIDDEN!" will be displayed as soon as the modal is closed.

Comment: I think I am initializing it correctly. Please take a look at the `Attempt 1` section of my question. The `submit` function is being called and `information.add` is getting stored in `localSstorage`. I don't understand why `information.subject` and `information.emailContent` aren't being stored.

Comment: I think if bootstrap wasn't initialised correctly, the event wouldn't trigger and `submit` wouldn't be called.

Comment: Have you tried to dump ( cosole.log($scope) ) to console and check what informations are stored inside? I think your problem might be a scope problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please take a look at the `Attempt 4` section of my question.

Comment: You put a console.log(emailContent); inside your submit function. What is it printing?
By the way. you can do things like this: console.log('emailContent',emailContent); to prefix your logs.

Comment: `console.log(emailContent)` is being called three times for some reason. The first time it prints the value entered by the user correctly. The second and third times it logs an empty array like so: `[]`. Thanks.

Comment: Try investigating were the multiple calls are comming from. I think your on to something. :)

Comment: Ok. I am going to try to do that. Please take a look at the `Attempt 5` section in my question.

Comment: I think the difference has something to do with this: ng-click="close(); clear()". These functions are only called on hitting the button.

Comment: Angular is calling the function multiple times. It looks like the $digest loop and watchers are rerun each time I change a `model` value. I am positive that this is not the cause of the problem. I think this is just Angular's expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This worked out for me, I referred to the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/)

```
var myModal = document.getElementById('timeupModal')
myModal.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    function_to_run();
})
```